# Finding splitting field over $\mathbb Q$

Tags: field-theory, splitting-field

How do I find a splitting field for the polynomial $x^3 - 10$ over $\mathbb Q[\sqrt2]$ ?

I know that elements of $\mathbb Q[\sqrt2]$ are of the form $a + \sqrt2 b$ where $a$ and $b$ are in $\mathbb Q$.

I am taking a course in field theory for the first time so have very less idea on how to proceed.

Comment: Can you see that the polynomial splits in $\Bbb Q[\sqrt 2,\sqrt[3]10,i,\sqrt 3]$? Is there a smaller field than this that works?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  I could figure out that the roots of the polynomial will be like $\sqrt[3]10w^i$ where $0\leq i \leq 3$